# How to fix Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How to fix Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)?

@Html.Raw(Model.FooterHtml)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input and output you're expecting and if you've attempted anything?

Comment: This is @Html.Raw in a razor template of MVC. and FooterHtml is a string type.

Comment: I am working on Veracode flaw and trying to fix this issue. nothing output specific need.

Comment: I wondder using Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode is not double encode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an explicit example of an HTML string you'd want to sanitize and the anticipated output post-sanitization, I can only provide a general suggestion that you leverage an HTML sanitization library.

It's a good idea to sanitize raw HTML when you receive it and before you store it, but if you're about to render HTML that is untrusted and has already been stored, you can perform sanitization in your controller when you generate your model and before you return it to your view.

https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

> **Usage**
>
> Install the HtmlSanitizer NuGet package. Then:
>
> ```
> var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
> var html = @"<script>alert('xss')</script><div onload=""alert('xss')"""
>     + @"style=""background-color: test"">Test<img src=""test.gif"""
>     + @"style=""background-image: url(javascript:alert('xss')); margin: 10px""></div>";
> var sanitized = sanitizer.Sanitize(html, "http://www.example.com");
> Assert.That(sanitized, Is.EqualTo(@"<div style=""background-color: test"">"
>     + @"Test<img style=""margin: 10px"" src=""http://www.example.com/test.gif""></div>"));
> ```

The above library offers a demo at https://xss.ganss.org/
and a Fiddle at https://dotnetfiddle.net/892nOk